# Why is it skipping Sprite.setTexture()?

Tags: c++, sfml, game-development

I have been trying to run my code and it has been skipping this line

```
this->tileSprite.setTexture(this->tileTexture);
```

within the constructor of my class Tile

```
Tile::Tile()
{
   int RNG = rand() % 3 + 1; // randomizer for texture loading

   this->pX = this->pY = 0;

   if (RNG == 1)
   {
       // loads pattern 1
       this->tileTexture.loadFromFile("Sprites/Ground/Unrevealed/Unrevealed Tile 1.png");
       this->tileSprite.setTexture(this->tileTexture);
   }

   else if (RNG == 2)
   {
       // loads pattern 2
       this->tileTexture.loadFromFile("Sprites/Ground/Unrevealed/Unrevealed Tile 2.png");
       this->tileSprite.setTexture(this->tileTexture);
   }

   else if (RNG == 3)
   {
       // loads pattern 3
       this->tileTexture.loadFromFile("Sprites/Ground/Unrevealed/Unrevealed Tile 3.png");
       this->tileSprite.setTexture(this->tileTexture);
   }
}
```

Here's also my Tile class

```
class Tile
{
public:
   // constructors
   Tile();
   ~Tile();

   // getters
   // data getters
   float getX();
   float getY();
   sf::Sprite getSprite();

    // list getters
   Tile* getNext();
   Tile* getPrev();
   int getListpos();

    //tile getters
   Tile* getLf();
   Tile* getRt();
   Tile* getUp();
   Tile* getDn();
   Tile* getClu();
   Tile* getCld();
   Tile* getCru();
   Tile* getCrd();


   //setters
   // data setters
   void setX(float newX);
   void setY(float newY);
   virtual void setSprite(sf::Texture& newTexture);
   void setSpritePos(float xPos, float yPos);

   // list setters
   void setNext(Tile* nextTile);
   void setPrev(Tile* prevTile);
   void setListpos(int Listpos);

   //tile setters
   void setLf(Tile* newLf);
   void setRt(Tile* newRt);
   void setUp(Tile* newUp);
   void setDn(Tile* newDn);
   void setClu(Tile* newClu);
   void setCld(Tile* newCld);
   void setCru(Tile* newCru);
   void setCrd(Tile* newCrd);

   //other functions


private:

   // data of the node
   float pX;
   float pY;
   sf::Sprite tileSprite;
   sf::Texture tileTexture;

   // postions of list
   Tile* tNext;
   Tile* tPrev;
   int Listpos;

   // postions of Tile
   Tile* Lf; // Left of the tile
   Tile* Rt; // right of the tile
   Tile* Up; // Up of the tile
   Tile* Dn; // down of the tile
   Tile* Clu; // conner left up of the tile
   Tile* Cld; // conner left down of the tile
   Tile* Cru; // conner right up of the tile
   Tile* Crd; // conner right down of the tile
};
```

Comment: It isn't skipping it.

Comment: @user253751 then why does it show that it is skipping it on my compiler and it isn't storing the texture

Comment: It's not skipping it. The problem is something else.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned in a comment that the issue is that the texture isn't being "stored".

Both lines are being executed but the second one won't be assigning the texture you expect if the texture didn't load correctly. If the loading fails, the texture is not changed.

Remember that [.loadFromFile returns a boolean](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Texture.php#a8e1b56eabfe33e2e0e1cb03712c7fcc7) that identifies whether that loading was successful or not so you should check that. If it's false (failing to load), you can then find out why it's not loading (most likely looking in the wrong location often due to the working directory).